# Jupyter: magic %qtconsole doesn't work

Tags: jupyter, qtconsole

I am trying to use the magic `%qtconsole` from jupyter notebook.
I am working on my local connected to a remote server.

WHen typing `%qtconsole`  and shift-enter in a cell of the notebook, nothing happens. No error message, but not qt console either.

Does that have to do with the remote server? Anyone has an idea how to resolve that problem?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. And I'm looking for a RStudio server style notebook-console integrated environment in browser.

Comment: Does `jupyter qtconsole` on the command line work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say much about your environment, but you may need to install qtconsole.  If you are in a conda environment try...

```
conda install qtconsole
```

... or in general...

```
pip install qtconsole
```

Comment: I did conda install qtconsole. But no help. Now, mine is remote access to the jupyter server. qtconsole is installed on the remote server. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know anything about working with jupyter and remote servers, sorry.